# Weird behavior in C printf

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior

I've the following piece of code.

```
    char str[MAXS];
    gets(str);
    N = strlen(str);

    for (i = N / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }

    for (i = N - 1; i > N / 2 - 1; i--) {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

For and input string, for example "I ENIL SIHTHSIREBBIG S", it should print simply "THIS LINE IS GIBBERISH". But it only prints the content of the second loop, but, if I insert a simple "\n" in the middle of the two loops, the content, the printf inside the first loop works. Whats's going on here, here comes the 'working' code (at least, I don't want that '\n' in the middle')

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <memory>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
#include <new>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <climits>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctime>

#define REP(i, n) for(int (i) = 0; i < n; i++)
#define FOR(i, a, n) for(int (i) = a; i < n; i++)
#define FORR(i, a, n) for(int (i) = a; i <= n; i++)
#define for_each(q, s) for(typeof(s.begin()) q=s.begin(); q!=s.end(); q++)
#define sz(n) n.size()
#define pb(n) push_back(n)
#define all(n) n.begin(), n.end()

template<typename T> T gcd(T a, T b) {
    if(!b) return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}
template<typename T> T lcm(T a, T b) {
    return a * b / gcd(a, b);
}

template<typename T> void chmin(T& a, T b) { a = (a > b) ? b : a; }
template<typename T> void chmax(T& a, T b) { a = (a < b) ? b : a; }
int in() { int x; scanf("%d", &x); return x; }

using namespace std;

typedef long long Int;
typedef unsigned uint;

const int MAXS = 107;

int N, T;
char str[MAXS];

int main(void) {
    scanf("%d ", &T);

    int i;

    for ( ; T--; ) {
        gets(str);
        N = strlen(str);

        for (i = N / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        }

        for (i = N - 1; i > N / 2 - 1; i--) {
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, after you get an answer (this is a good question, after all) can you then try this without `gets`?  It is an awful function that is known to be a major security hole. And besides, [it's been removed from C as of C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gets()#gets).

Comment: I know it's ugly, but I don't know another way to read a full line with empty spaces in a C string

Comment: The error likely lies somewhere else and it is not caught until other parts of the code are executed. It's not uncommon to see a `printf` do wonders.

Comment: @JefersonSiqueira Use `fgets` or `gets_s` to replace `gets`.

Comment: [Your code appears to work on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/a0lTV4)

Comment: Jacob is right.  Works for me: http://ideone.com/dekrcs  Maybe you have some kind of weird carriage return or control character in your code that the linefeed fixes up?

Comment: It's curious, I'll update my full code up there. It worked in ideone with me too, but I get this behavior O my pc, by the ways, it's Intel I7 over Elementary OS 64bits in G++ 4.6

Comment: I can't see any issue in the code that would cause that "weird" behavior. Actually, I tested it and it works as it should. So, probably the error is not in the code you're showing but in the part of the code you're not showing. Please, provide the declarations of i, MAXS and N.

Comment: That's an awful lot of headers for not very much code!  In fact, there's an awful lot of irrelevant material in the code.  Please learn about how to create SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) without extraneous material. FYI: You can use the `getline` function to get lines into C++ strings: `string data; if (getline(cin, data)) { ...use data... }`.

Comment: There is no "undefined behavior", other than the exact handling of printing an `\r`. In the OPs system, this repositions the cursor to the left of the current line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 73 lines of code in your program in the question, 50 of which are irrelevant to the workings of the program. Please study how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people don't have to wade through 3 times as much code as necessary.

Here's a 22 line program that works:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

const int MAXS = 107;

int main(void)
{
    char str[MAXS];

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != 0)
    {
        int N = strlen(str);
        if (str[N-1] == '\n')
            str[--N] = '\0';
        for (int i = N / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        for (int i = N - 1; i > N / 2 - 1; i--)
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is C++ in name only; it uses the `<cstring>` and `<cstdio>` headers, but if you changed those to `<string.h>` and `<stdio.h>`, it would be C code.
Note that it checks for buffer overflow (using `fgets()` — never, ever use `gets()`!) and tests that data was read. It doesn't bother with a count of the lines of input; it can detect EOF reliably.  It removes the trailing newline that `fgets()` leaves but `gets()` does not.  It then prints the first half of the string backwards, and then the second half of the string backwards.  I didn't make any substantive changes to the logic of the two printing loops.  I did remove the global variables; you should avoid them too, though sometimes global variables are necessary (whereas `gets()` is just poison and should never be used).

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work. At least as this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 1024
int main() {
  char str[MAXS];
  int N;
  int i;

  gets(str);
  N = strlen(str);

  for (i = N / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%c", str[i]);
  }

  for (i = N - 1; i > N / 2 - 1; i--) {
    printf("%c", str[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Check your MAXS define. No other clue, sorry !

Edit: Oh! you're doing C++, actually...